# How to modify existing text within Header and Footer word document using Python docx

Tags: python, automation, ms-word, header, docx

Hi wonder if it possible to modify existing text within header and footer within word doc in python, using python docx.

Example on what I'm looking for.

[image]

I want to be able to write some code that can find text within the header or footer
It will be 'December 2020' for example and to be able to edit it to 'January 2021'

What has been done so far

```
from docx import Document

doc=Document('./word.docx')
Dictionary = {"2020": "2021", "December":"January"
for i in Dictionary:
    for p in doc.paragraphs:
        if p.text.find(i)>=0:
           p.text=p.text.replace(i,Dictionary[i])
            
doc.save('./word_doc2.docx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already present in the documentation of the `python-docx` library, you can find it [Here](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/header.html?highlight=footer). Otherwise, here is a simple script that does what you want (adapt it for your need):

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

# read  doc
doc = Document('./word.docx')

# define your style font and size for the header 
style_h = doc.styles['Header']
font_h = style_h.font
font_h.name = 'Arial'
font_h.bold = True
font_h.size = Pt(20)

# define your style font and size for the footer
style_f = doc.styles['Footer']
font_f = style_f.font
font_f.name = 'Aharoni'
font_f.bold = False
font_f.size = Pt(10)

# for the header:
header = doc.sections[0].header
paragraph_h = header.paragraphs[0]
paragraph_h.text = 'January 2021' # insert new value here.
paragraph_h.style = doc.styles['Header'] # this is what changes the style

# for the footer:
footer = doc.sections[0].footer
paragraph_f = footer.paragraphs[0]
paragraph_f.text = 'January 2021' # insert new value here.
paragraph_f.style = doc.styles['Footer']# this is what changes the style

doc.save('./word_doc2.docx')
```

N.B: This work on only one page docs, you can easily add a loop if you want to apply the same thing to all the pages (or use pre-set functions from the `docx` library.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was also wondering if it is possible to change the font and size of the text within the header and footer. Been looking at the documentation and elsewhere can I can't find this?

Comment: yes there is , and also in the doc :) , here, I changed the code so that it does what you want, check it! (by the way I change random values of size and text type just to give you an example, you can put whatever you want) dont forget to mark it as answered if you got what you want :)

Comment: Thanks again, I'm not sure if it is recent thing, code paragraph_f_style = doc.styles['Footer'] I get the error KeyError: "no style with name 'footer'"  I'm pretty sure this worked last time.. I also having issues separating the fonts/size for both the header and footer. I seem to get the same style on both, no matter what I do.

Comment: I tried the code on my computer before handing it to you, I have python 3.10, which version do you have  ?

Comment: python 3.7.6 with anaconda. Maybe that's got something to do with it.

Comment: Thank you. Tried python 3.8 and that seems to have got it to worked now.